# HOW TO COPY INTERACTIVE IMAGE

Tags: images, copy

I would like to ask if is somehow an easy way to copy an interactive image from website?
Lets say this site https://metar-taf.com/. It has an image that is updated and when you mouse over you see the updated information.
I would like to have an option to screen shot the image but having the same result lets say i could mouse over and see the same information.
After a while taking a new screenshot and mouse over i will have the update information....
Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're asking is quite likely violating copyright.

Comment: No, such a thing is not possible with a mouseover.  You could record a video and convert to gif.